# Pressing more than one GUI element at a time in Unity

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing controls for a mobile platform; my GUI takes up the left, center, and right thirds of the screen.  When the player wants to jump, they press the center button.  My problem is that it seems that only one GUI element is being allowed to be pressed at once (like the device has only one mouse cursor that moves) rather than me being allowed to jump and go right at the same time.  My code:

```
// JavaScript
#pragma strict

static var guiLeft : int = 0;
static var guiRight : int = 0;
static var guiJump : int = 0;

function OnGUI () {

// leftarrow
if (GUI.RepeatButton (Rect (0,0,Screen.width/3,Screen.height), "", GUIStyle.none)) {
    guiLeft = 1;

    }
    else{
    guiLeft = 0;
    }


// right
if (GUI.RepeatButton (Rect (Screen.width-Screen.width/3,0,Screen.width/3,Screen.height), "", GUIStyle.none)) {
    guiRight = 1;
    }
    else{
    guiRight = 0;
    }

            // jump
if (GUI.RepeatButton (Rect (Screen.width/3,0,(Screen.width/3)+2,Screen.height), "", GUIStyle.none)) {
    guiJump = 1;
    }
    else{
    guiJump = 0;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity GUI only supports one inputsource at a time (for example the left mouse button, or the right mouse button). The correct way to tackle your problem would be to use `Input.touches`. That'd indeed mean you'll have to change a lot of things in your game.

Comment: That seems like such a silly thing for Unity to do when they brand themselves as easily multiplatform.  
How exactly would I set up Input.touches?  Is there a way to simulate pressing a keyboard key on touch?

Comment: @AlexanderLozada I kinda understand where your frustation comes from, but you'll have to think about a menu where you can simultaniously 'click' multiple options. That makes no sense. You can't simulate a keyboard key on touch, unless you bring the keyboard of your phone up. About the touches example, look at this here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html

Comment: Where exactly would I apply this code?  Is it possible on a GUI element - or do I have to go through the GUI Textures and then apply that script there?

Comment: @AlexanderLozada I'm unsure about that. What I'd do would be putting in some cubes for example and attach the script there. Then your menu would be 3D which can be a good thing. But I'm unsure if it's possible with GUI elements.